# error Code 404 not found when run project from root from public run normal

Tags: php, laravel, routes, custom-error-pages

In my issue when i am try to call any route from subdomain root return laravel error 404 not Found
however when i am try to run project from subfolder /public inside project run normal and route call normal

for example :
when i am call url : [www.example.com/myprojectroot](http://www.example.com/myprojectroot)
Return : 404 not found like screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdVFT.png)

But when i am call any route from url : [www.example.com/myprojectroot/public/anydefine](http://www.example.com/myprojectroot/public/anydefine) route
in this case route call normal but some assest not working

so that i need to call any route from main root not from subfolder public how can i do that

and this my .htaccess code on subdomain root

`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I AM TRY TO CHANGE ON .HTACCESS BUT RETURN 403 FORBIDDEN

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Apache. Try to add this to its configuration (Usually its here  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd. conf)

```
<Directory /var/www/yourproject/> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And you also need to enable pretty urls (I think your laravel version is old)
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls

Comment: No i am use bluehost as project host

Comment: and laravel version 8.1

Comment: Bluehost is a hosting service. The server itself uses apache.

Check your Cpanel to know for sure.
I think this article shows that their servers are apache.
https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/create-apache-handlers